# How to round off the float values in graph using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
b.yAxis().setLFormat('{value|' + parseInt(myvalue[7],10)+ '}');
```

Above code snippet returns values as "0.2" and increments by 0.2,0.4,0.6 but I need this whole number like 1,2,3,4....Found allowDecimals: false option but not sure how to pass to get the round value.Can somehelp  me.

Comment: In a pinch, you can always use the `Math.floor()` function. You can add 0.5 to the number to be floored in order to get a "rounding" effect.

Comment: thank you so much for response I changed the line of code into b.yAxis().setLFormat('{value|' + Math.floor(myvalue[7])+ '}');  but still i see the same response.Very new to js world.Pls bare.

Answer (score 0):

I had missed it: you want to display only the integer ticks **in the graph**, not to round off your float values. That's a different matter. You need to check on the documentation for the library you're using.

First off, **you need to tell us what library you're using**. From what you say (setLFormat, allowDecimals, javascript) I believe you're using HighStock.

Then you check either the documentation or the user forums for the relevant software. In this case you're in luck, [the documentation is exhaustive](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.allowDecimals). You may have already checked out that page, but possibly you did not notice the links to the examples.

Also, the structure of the property JSON is given on the left hand side of the page; as you can see the `allowDecimals` for `yAxis` must be supplied on the HighChart container call, not on each single value.

You can see its use from this fiddle ([click here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/allowdecimals-true/)).

You need to specify, for Y axis,

```
 yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Flats'
        },
        allowDecimals: false
    },
```

If you need BOTH effects (integer points **and** integer grid), then you need apply both methods: set `allowDecimals` to false, and use `Math.floor(value)` or `Math.round(value)` instead of `value` on each value.

<sup>If my guesses are correct *and* this answer works, apart from accepting it :-), you may want to edit your title to reflect the fact that you're using HighStock JS library and you want it to use an integer grid. This is possibly the reason why you got downvoted; you may want [to check out this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). (None of us started out asking good questions - I know that I definitely did *not*.)</sup>